# AForge Convertation and problems with HD

Tags: c#, video, video-capture, aforge

First of all, I can't play and record HD video(1920x1080), when I change my camera resolution to 1920x1080 program show and record black background, if camera resolution is 720x576 it works without problems. I'm sure that the problem is in my solution because, when I use DesktopVideo(Software which is included with Blackmagic Decklink Studio 2) it shows HD video from camera. 
Second, How do I convert video with AForge? like changing resolution and framerate, I can change codecs and bitrate, but when I change Resolution and FrameRate in "FileWriter.Open"
 command I get Error Resolution and FrameRate must be the same as Bitmap I'm capturing from camera.

If anybody knows how to solve these problems please share information, thanks!

Here is the code

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.ComponentModel;

using System.Data;

using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using AForge.Video.FFMPEG;
using AForge.Video.VFW;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication12
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private FilterInfoCollection VideoCaptureDevices;

        private VideoCaptureDevice FinalVideo = null;
        private VideoCaptureDeviceForm captureDevice;
        private Bitmap video;
        //private AVIWriter AVIwriter = new AVIWriter();
        private VideoFileWriter FileWriter = new VideoFileWriter();
        private SaveFileDialog saveAvi;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            VideoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            captureDevice = new VideoCaptureDeviceForm();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /////capture device list
            if (captureDevice.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
                FinalVideo = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
                FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
                FinalVideo.Start();
            }
        }
        void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (butStop.Text == "Stop Record")
            {
                video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                //AVIwriter.Quality = 0;
                FileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(video);
                //AVIwriter.AddFrame(video);
            }
            else
            {
                video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ////record button
            saveAvi = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveAvi.Filter = "Avi Files (*.avi)|*.avi";
            if (saveAvi.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                int h = captureDevice.VideoDevice.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Height;
                int w = captureDevice.VideoDevice.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Width;
                FileWriter.Open(saveAvi.FileName, w, h,25,VideoCodec.Default,5000000);
                FileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(video);

                //AVIwriter.Open(saveAvi.FileName, w, h);
                butStop.Text = "Stop Record";
                //FinalVideo = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
                //FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
                //FinalVideo.Start();
            }
        }

        private void butStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (butStop.Text == "Stop Record")
            {
                butStop.Text = "Stop";
                if (FinalVideo == null)
                { return; }
                if (FinalVideo.IsRunning)
                {
                    //this.FinalVideo.Stop();
                    FileWriter.Close();
                    //this.AVIwriter.Close();
                    pictureBox1.Image = null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.FinalVideo.Stop();
                FileWriter.Close();
                //this.AVIwriter.Close();
                pictureBox1.Image = null;
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image.Save("IMG" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss") + ".jpg");
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (FinalVideo == null)
            { return; }
            if (FinalVideo.IsRunning)
            {
                this.FinalVideo.Stop();
                FileWriter.Close();
                //this.AVIwriter.Close();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided code simply captures and saves in the format currently active/selected for the capture device. In general, resolution change is an "expensive" operation is not available as a complimentary operation.

You want to change resolution right on capture device by switching it to more appropriate format, then capture in this resolution and have all further data manipulation in correct resolution. Available resolutions and options might be hardware specific there.

If/when no suitable capture resolution option is available, you typically resample the video to new resolution. Even though Windows API has suitable functionality, in your particular case you are interested to have this integrated with AForge library and you need to check its documentation to find out whether it provides a respective wrapper and whether it can be integrated into capture process overall (or, you need to write this code yourself to handle scaling).

Comment: I'm not converting anything. When I change option on capture device(Camera) from HD to FullHD it shows black screen, when it is HD it works fine

Comment: Blackmagic devices deliver blackness if configuration does not match signal source and/or format. You are responsible for setting up the source filter correctly (correct resolution, correct source either programmatically or by changing respective default in Control Panel for this device). The fact that Desktop Video works fine does not prove that you can capture video using filter. Desktop Video does not use the filter you use, instead they both share DeckLink SDK for capture, and Blackmagic already obsoleted the DirectShow interface you are using.